# Running build.gradle of a library distributed through Artifactory

Tags: android, build, gradle, dependency-management, artifactory

Is it somehow possible to run build.gradle file of a library distributed through artifactory repository when the main project builds ?

Specific case: In library's build.gradle I copy some files from root directory to another directory. This works well if the dependency on the library is declared as `compile project(':lib-trololo')`, but I would like to distribute the lib through Artifactory, but as there is only .aar file, the library's build is not run again when building main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no".

1. Artifactory does not contain any build tool in it. It's not a build server that *does* things, it's a binary repository that *stores* things.
2. Anyhow, the move works on your machine cause you rely on a project layout of your source files (`compile project(':lib-trololo')`is a source-level dependency). Once the file is packed as a binary, there is no source structure anymore, but only a single file with compiled classes and metadata.

You should reconsider your build.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. I just thought maybe some hack I couldn't even think of might exist. :-)